# Resource Recommendations: Extended Supersymmetry in 2+1 Dimensions

Tags: resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, superconformality

I'm interested in comprehensive resource recommendations covering extended supersymmetry (all cases) in 2+1 dimensions with the aim of understanding topics such as 2+1 dimensional SCFTs [ABJ(M), BLG models], Witten-Seiberg dualities, etc.